# What to do about all the wannabe-epidemiologist questions that propose to redefine CFR?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've lost count of these, but besides' the HNQ'd one there have been numerous dupes, but all of them have one thing in common, they weave some naive (conspiracy?) theory that the true [CFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_fatality_rate) ("death rate") is about 40% for Covid-19. That the first question got HNQd is perhaps understandable, but unfortunately it seems to have blown wind into subsequent questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These should simply be closed as a duplicate of: [Does COVID-19 have a mortality rate of 41%?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20970/does-covid-19-have-a-mortality-rate-of-41)

If that question does not seem sufficiently catch-all, we could edit it to be more general and cover the answers given.

I don't feel like it's worth any more effort on this line of questioning: it's misguided and as suggested here has a smell of conspiracy theory that isn't grounded in any sort of truth.

Comment: note: I edited the title slightly to try to be a bit more catch-all and include the equation for calculating CFR, since that's the core of the question rather than a particular number.

Answer (score 0):

Where there is moving data depending various factors, then maybe create a community wiki with an answer and keep updating that?

Comment: I don't think this is a good candidate for a community wiki. Wikis are good for questions like "what are some ways to solve this?" but not so good for "what is the correct solution?" My knowledge of epidemiology is thin but I'm pretty sure CFR is well defined and has a _correct_ answer.

Comment: the case fatality rate depends on who is being diagnosed and at what time  so will differ from country to country depending on how they are being diagnosed and over what time period as well as possibly what strain of the virus.  That's why I was suggesting a wiki because there are too many variables.